# fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(realm:schema:)' for class MyApp.User

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Im getting this error when i try to load a user from the database.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let users = realm.objects(User)
        print(users)
    }


class User: Object, Mappable {

  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var userName = ""

required init() {
    super.init()
}

// MARK: Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["Id"]
    name <- map["Name"]
    userName <- map["UserName"]
}

required init?(_ map: Map) { super.init() }
```

}

I tried implemeting that init method but i get (Use of undeclared identifier RLMObjectSchema):
[image]

Any hints?

Comment: According to RealmSwift's `Object` source it seems that the initializer you're trying to override shouldn't be used as it's for internal use only.

Answer (score 1):

When I use realm, I will only use convenience init.

In your case

```
class User: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var userName = ""

    // MARK: Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["Id"]
        name <- map["Name"]
        userName <- map["UserName"]
    }

    convenience init?(_ map: Map) { self.init() }
}
```

If you want implement designate init, you should implement

```
init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}
```

When you implement designate `init()`, swift will not inherit other designate init methods which are required by realm.

Comment: I can't implement init(realm:schema), see my picture above, realm doesnt know about RLMRealm/RLMObjectSchema

Comment: add `import Realm`, Why don't you use conveniece init?

Comment: @Yon, As I used convenience init?(_ map: Map) { self.init() }, its still giving me compile time error "Initializer requirement  init can only be satisfied by a required Initializer in non-final class ", what could be issue can you help?